# How to create an interface in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, interface, protocols

i want to create functionality like interface in swift, my goal is when i call another class suppose i'm calling API and the response of that class i want to reflect in to my current screen, in android interface is used to achieve but what should i use in swift for that? can anyone help me with example. the code for android is given below...

```
public class ExecuteServerReq {
    public GetResponse getResponse = null;

    public void somemethod() {
        getResponse.onResponse(Response);
    } 
    public interface GetResponse {
        void onResponse(String objects);
    }
}


ExecuteServerReq executeServerReq = new ExecuteServerReq();

executeServerReq.getResponse = new ExecuteServerReq.GetResponse() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String objects) {
    }
}
```

Comment: in swift protocol works as interface.Google protocol in swift.

Comment: You can create protocol for achieve same

Comment: @TusharSharma any give me example ..

Comment: @MikeAlter  how.... any example ???

Comment: @Jaypraksh Sing countless tutorials and solutions on stack are already present please google .

Comment: Look for protocols in Swift. They are semantically very close to Java interfaces. There are no anonymous classes in Swift. You should use closures instead. You can probably avoid your interface / protocol by using closures.

Comment: You should use clouser instead of protocol for ws calling

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Instead of interface swift have **Protocols**.

A protocol defines a blueprint of methods, properties, and other requirements that suit a particular task or piece of functionality. The protocol can then be adopted by a class, structure, or enumeration to provide an actual implementation of those requirements. Any type that satisfies the requirements of a protocol is said to conform to that protocol.

lets take an exam .

```
protocol Animal {
    func canSwim() -> Bool
}
```

and we have a class that confirm this protocol name Animal

```
class Human : Animal {
   func canSwim() -> Bool {
     return true
   }
}
```

for more go to - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for `Protocols'. Interfaces are the same as protocols in Swift.

```
protocol Shape {
    func shapeName() -> String
}

class Circle: Shape {
    func shapeName() -> String {
        return "circle"
    }
  
}

class Triangle: Shape {
    func shapeName() -> String {
        return "triangle"
    }
}
```

`class` and `struct` both can implements the `protocol`.