# How to create implement multi protocol in one ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-protocols

I would like to create a protocol that has different activities. my reference is an interface on Java Android that we can able create a variable as an interface then we initialize like we implement in class. so, what the equivalent of the interface on swift code?

```
//Android Interface
private OnValueChanged joinDay, birthDay;

//initialize
joinDay = new OnValueChanged(value -> {
//somecode
});

birthday = new OnValueChanged(value -> {
//somecode
});


interface OnValueChanged{
   void didChanged(Date value)
}

//END OF ANDROID INTERFACE








//SWIFT PROTOCOL

class myClass : OnValueChanged{


func didChanged(Int value){
//somecode
}

}

protocol OnValueChanged{
    func didChanged(Int value)
}

//END OF SWIFT PROTOCOL
```

What I want is to create a variable or something like that, which could implement different codes for the same Class like on Android Side.

how to do that in swift?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an interface in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45974041/how-to-create-an-interface-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a separate type for this in Swift. Your Java interface can be represented with a *closure* in Swift. Specifically, it is a closure of type `(Int) -> Void`.

You can declare `joinDay` and `birthday` like this in Swift:

```
var joinDay: ((Int) -> Void)?
var birthday: ((Int) -> Void)?
```

To assign an "implementation", do:

```
joinDay = { value in
    // do something with the parameter "value"
    print(value)
}
```

And the equivalent of calling `joinDay.didChanged(someValue)` in Swift would be:

```
joinDay?(someValue)
```

For more info on how to use closures, see [Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) in the Swift Guide.